# calculate all possible values of the following integral

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula

Can someone help me: Assuming that none of the points $0$, $1$ and $-1$ lies on $L$, calculate all possible values of the integral
$$
\mathop{\int}\limits_{L}{\frac{dz}{{z}{\mathrm{(}}{z}^{2}\mathrm{{-}}{1}{\mathrm{)}}}}\text{,}
$$

for various positions of    $
L
$
.

Comment: I am just thinking about cauchy's integral and how we can use it

Comment: What's $L{}{}$?

Comment: I think it's any close rectifable curve

Comment: Is there any hint

Answer (score 0):

We have $z(z^2-1) = z(z+1)(z-1)$.

Calculating the residues, we have:

\begin{align}
\text{Res}\left(\frac{1}{z(z+1)(z-1)},0\right)&=\lim\limits_{z\rightarrow0}\frac{1}{(z+1)(z-1)}=-1\\
\text{Res}\left(\frac{1}{z(z+1)(z-1)},1\right)&=\lim\limits_{z\rightarrow1}\frac{1}{z(z+1)}=\frac{1}{2}\\
\text{Res}\left(\frac{1}{z(z+1)(z-1)},-1\right)&=\lim\limits_{z\rightarrow-1}\frac{1}{z(z-1)}=\frac{1}{2}
\end{align}

Now, by the Residue Theorem, we have

$$\oint_L\frac{dz}{z(z^2-1)}=2\pi i\sum_k\text{Res}\left(\frac{1}{z(z+1)(z-1)},z_k\right)$$

where $z_k$ are the zeros of the denominator of the function that are enclosed by L.

For example, if $L$ is a circle about the origin with radius $R>1$, we have

$$\oint_L\frac{dz}{z(z^2-1)}=2\pi i\left(-1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\right)=0$$

Comment: Why did we take the sum of the values in the final step ?

Comment: The value of a contour integral in the complex plane along a closed path is the sum of all the residues at singularities of the integrand that are enclosed within this contour, multiplied with $2\pi i$. If you have a circle about the origin with radius $R>1$, then all three singularities of your function are enclosed within it, thus we sum over all the residues.